# Qt6. Есть ли функция strtok()

Tags: qt, qt6

Есть ли в Qt6 функция strtok() или ее аналог?

Нужно посчитать число одинаковых слов в массиве

Comment: если для разбивки, то есть QString::split

Comment: Нужно количество одинаковых слов в строке посчитать

Comment: тогда QString::indexOf наверное

Comment: а почему strtok() в Qt нельзя использовать?

Comment: Можно использовать strtok в qt, как и любую другую с-функцию. Читайте мануал и вперёд. Но в QString есть функция count, которая как раз для вашего случая https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#count

Comment: Спасибо большое!